# C++ Help to define and use a vector of vector of a struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct

My intention is to build such a data structure in C++:

```
struct callbackDataUnit {
    std::string columnName;
    std::string columnData;
};

std::vector<callbackDataUnit> callbackRow;

std::vector<callbackRow> callbackSet; <--- Invalid... It needs a type here
```

The compiler first complains about the lack os `static` on `callbackRow`. Even if I use `static` there, it still does not compile as the structure is naturally invalid

I would like to take this opportunity to understand a little more about C++ (I´m a beginner on that area), so here goes my questions:

a) Why do we need the `static` qualifier here ?

b) How can I solve this matrix of the first variables ? I could create 3 classes here (`CallbackDataUnit`, `CallbackRow` and `CallbackSet`) but I feel I would be missing real C++ power here. Would it make sense to make `callbackRow` a single element `struct`, so that it can be added to `callbackSet` ?

Thanks for helping

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<callbackDataUnit>>` ? (and maybe you forgot the word `typedef` in front of both of your decls, hard to say),  that said (b) is pretty open ended, can you narrow that down a little?

Comment: This is a valid option, but I wouldn´t separate the types here...

Comment: I didn't, so I'm not sure what you're talking about when you say "wouldn't". Do you mean "wouldn't want to?" The posted code had a glaring problem; you were using a `var` where there should be a *type*.  If that isn't the meat of your problem, elaborate on what is.

Comment: Thanks for the insight, but R Sahu got it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want define new types, not variables.

To do that, you can use `typedef` or `using`.

```
typedef std::vector<callbackDataUnit> callbackRow;
typedef std::vector<callbackRow> callbackSet;

using callbackRow = std::vector<callbackDataUnit>;
using callbackSet = std::vector<callbackRow>;
```

If you want to just define variables, you can use:

```
std::vector<callbackDataUnit> callbackRow;
std::vector<decltype(callbackRow)> callbackSet;
```

Comment: That´s exactly what I wanna do... Thanks for helpingBTW: No need for `static` here ?

Comment: You don't need `static` if you want to define new types.